# Failed to connect mariadb container by Mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

Hi i trying to connect to Mariadb container by msql.
I did it only with Ip address

```
  k19@k19:~$ docker inspect mariadb | grep IPAddress
    "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
    k19@k19:~$ mysql -u root -p -h 172.17.0.2
```

But my instructor want that I do that with `--link` option, without using an address, and without installing mysql on local computer

Comment: Well, what is the question?

Comment: @obe how connect to mariadb container using mysql and --link option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the containers can actually reach another by using docker networking. I think that more information is needed to be more specific but the following overview is definitely going to help you:

https://runnable.com/docker/basic-docker-networking